# How can I make a SQL script run after a certain time without waiting for it?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, delay, delayed-execution

I'm trying to create a SQL script with a delay.

I could use:

```
blah blah
WAITFOR DELAY '00:30:00'
blah blah
```

but using a script like this requires that I sit through the 30 minutes.

Leaving the website will cancel the script.

---

The problem is that I want to change something in a table, and then change it back automatically 30 minutes later.

The person making the change will leave the webpage, so any kind of **client-side** script is out of the question.

Nor can I wait for the person to return and make the change if 30 minutes have passed, the change must happen after 30 minutes regardless.

---

Is there anyway to do this without making a service or any other program on the server?

Using only ASP/SQL programming.

If this is impossible, how do I make a **service** or **program** on the server to make this change?

Must be able to start this from the website using ASP.

Comment: If you do this server-side from ASP, leaving the website will not cancel the script, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by using **SQL Server Agent** and **SQL procedures**.

This is basically how my code is built up now:

*Make the temporary change in the table*

```
UPDATE table SET column = 'temp_value' WHERE column = 'normal_value'
```

*Check if the procedure is there, if so, delete it. Create a procedure to revert the changes in the table.*

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * 
    FROM sys.objects 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'myRevertProcedure')
        AND type IN ( N'P', N'PC' ) )
    DROP PROCEDURE myRevertProcedure 

CREATE PROCEDURE myRevertProcedure 
    AS
    BEGIN 
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:30:00'
        UPDATE table SET column = 'normal_value' WHERE column = 'temp_value'
    END
```

---

*I've created a **job** in the SQL Server Agent that runs the following:*

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * 
    FROM sys.objects 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'myRevertProcedure')
        AND type IN ( N'P', N'PC' ) )
    BEGIN
        EXEC MyProc
        DROP PROCEDURE myRevertProcedure 
    END
```

The reason the job does not simply revert the change itself is because the user shall set the delay.

*If the delay were allways to be 30 mins, I could've made the job run the following:*

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'temp_value')
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:30:00'
        UPDATE table SET column = 'normal_value' WHERE column = 'temp_value'
    END
```

By doing this, I would not need any procedure.

BTW: The job runs every few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I personally would not approach the situation this way. I don't know exactly what your data structure is, or why you need to change something for 30 minutes, but I would use a 'Change' table.

So you might have something like

**MainTable** (ID, Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4);

**ChangeTable** (ID, Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, CreatedDateTime);

Whenever you make your change instead of updating your main table you can simply insert the values you would be updating to into the ChangeTable (I'm assuming SQL-Server based on `WAITFOR`).

I would then make a view like so:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MainView
AS
SELECT  m.ID,
        Column1 = ISNULL(c.Column1, m.Column1),
        Column2 = ISNULL(c.Column2, m.Column2),
        Column3 = ISNULL(c.Column3, m.Column3)
FROM    dbo.MainTable m
        OUTER APPLY 
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 c.Column1, c.Column2, c.Column3
            FROM    dbo.ChangeTable c
            WHERE   c.ID = m.ID
            AND     c.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE())
            ORDER BY c.CreatedDate DESC
        ) c;
```

Then refer to this throughout the website.

If space is an issue you could set up a nightly Job to delete any old entries, e.g. set the following to run at 00:30

```
DELETE  ChangeTable
WHERE   CreatedDate < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, although others on this board would never think it is professional... I use website uptime monitoring services to run scripts.  For example this one will hit an asp page of your choosing every 30 minutes http://www.serviceuptime.com/free_monitoring.php.

For ease of development I use different monitoring services to load scripts.  There are more professional ways of doing so such as making a VBS script and running it through the Task Manager which I do for long running scripts but for simple things like checking a mail queue every so often I just use a monitoring service to load the page often enough to do what I want.

Comment: This is actually quite clever. I've found a nice solution to my problem, but I will keep your idea in mind in the future for more simple scripts.